# MySQL join - unknown column in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to this, therefore I have little idea on how this works, but I'm having an error with this:

```
USE database;
SELECT students.last_name, students.first_name,
       subjects.subject_name, entries.date_of_exam
FROM students,
     entries,
     subjects
       JOIN entries e1
         on  (e1.student_id = students.student_id)
         AND students.last_name IN (SELECT students.student_id FROM students)
       JOIN entries e2 on (e2.subject_id = subjects.subject_id)
ORDER BY last_name;
```

This comes up with the error

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'students.student_id' in 'on clause'

Even though that's the name of the column, so it should work?

What I'm trying to do is display all the entries for all the students, where each student has more than one entry, and also show the subjects.

Comment: You are doing cartesian products on students, entries and subjects. That can't be what you want, right? Try not mixing old-style comma-separated tables and ANSI join style.

Comment: at least this part will definitely not work  `AND students.last_name IN (SELECT students.student_id FROM students)` because last_name is not student_id

Comment: And this makes no sense: `students.last_name IN (SELECT students.student_id FROM students)`. You want a name to equal a student ID?

Comment: Scope issue. JOIN chains are evaluated before comma separated table lists. Don't mix old comma separated implicit joins with modern explicit joins!

Comment: Don't mix implicit and explicit join styles. In fact don't use implicit/comma join at all.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a comma separate list of tables in the `from` clause and then add `join`. The comma separated list will make the full Cartesian product of all records in all three tables. That will just explode the number of combinations and relate things in your output which are unrelated.

The `join` part is also strange, as you already have `entries` and then join it in twice again... There is nothing in your query that suggests that you actually need three times that table.

Furthermore the join condition `students.last_name IN (SELECT students.student_id FROM students)` makes no sense, as it requires the student's name to match the ID of some other (or same) student. Is there any student who is called `007` maybe?

Probably you just a query like this, which takes all info for each student, then joins with a query that selects the number entries per student, and finally filters for the cases where this count is greater than 1:

```
SELECT   s.last_name, 
         s.first_name, 
         s.subject_name, 
         e.date_of_exam
FROM     students s
JOIN     entries e
      ON s.student_id = e.student_id 
JOIN     subjects s
      ON e.subject_id = s.subject_id
JOIN     (SELECT   student_id, count(*) entry_count 
          FROM     entries
          GROUP BY student_id) cnt
      ON cnt.student_id = s.student_id
WHERE    cnt.entry_count > 1
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

try with something like:

```
SELECT students.last_name, students.first_name, subjects.subject_name, entries.date_of_exam
FROM students
INNER JOIN entries ON entries.student_id = students.student_id
INNER JOIN subjects ON subjects.subject_id = entries.subject_id
WHERE students.student_id IN (SELECT student_id FROM entries GROUP BY student_id HAVING COUNT(entries.subject_id ) > 1)    
ORDER BY last_name;
```